# How-to add a line break in the terminal after running powershell code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

[image]

Is there a way to add a line break between the finished script that was ran and the next command line prompt in VSCode. In the ISE console for powershell it skips a couple lines to make it easier to read. I browsed the web looking for an answer, but I don't think I was wording my search properly. Any ideas would be helpfully.

Comment: see `get-help about_prompts -Full`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the `about_prompts` help file noted by Kory Gill (by running `get-help about_prompts -Full`) then there are lots of examples on changing the default prompt behavior.

Run `(Get-Command Prompt).ScriptBlock` to get the default layout. My default `Prompt` function:

```
"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
```

To add two line breaks after previous code output, run this:

```
Function Prompt {
"

PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
}
```

To have these settings persist, you need to add the modified function to your PowerShell profile. 
Copy the above code (or what you come up with to your liking) and add that to your profile script in C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowershell\Profile.ps1 as documented in `about_Profiles`. This will make the desired prompt behavior persist, and will also apply in the embedded PowerShell terminal in vscode. These are the documented profile script locations in `about_Profiles`:

```
Description                Path
-----------                ----
Current User, Current Host $Home\[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1
Current User, All Hosts    $Home\[My ]Documents\Profile.ps1
All Users, Current Host    $PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
All Users, All Hosts       $PsHome\Profile.ps1
```

Run `help about_Profiles -Full` to learn more about profiles.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me. Do you know how I could also add another function to the one you mentioned about? Like combine the too?

function Prompt {
Write-Host '[' -NoNewline
Write-Host (Get-Date -UFormat '%m/$d/%y %T') -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
Write-Host ']:' -NoNewline
Write-Host (Get-Location | %{$_.path}) -NoNewline
return "> "
}
set-location c:\
clear-host

Comment: You can add as many functions to your profile as you like. I don't know what you mean by combine the two though. Do you mean that you want multiple prompt behaviors to be available, and for you to be able to change the prompt behavior at will?

Comment: Well, I would like to have "[01/10/19 15:04:27]:C:\>" in the terminal but also have the line break that you mentioned above. In my mind I was thinking that I would have to combine both of the functions in order to accomplish this. Or is it not something that is possible to have in vscode?

Comment: Please read the help content. You're expected to do some research on your own, and the help file I and Kory Gill mentioned tells you how to do such a thing. With that, here is the code you need `Function Prompt {
    $date = Get-Date -Format G
    "[$date]:$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
}`